# How do I clone a solution (with a different name) in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, solution

The `F#` compiler requires that the files in a solution must be kept ordered according to their dependencies. In my experience this makes it time consuming to make a new solution based on an old one.

For example, suppose I have a solution called `OldSolution` and I want to create another solution, identical except for naming, called `NewSolution`.

The most obvious way to do this would seem to be to copy the `OldSolution` folder to the same directory, renaming the copy to `NewSolution`. This fails because many items in the copy remain named as 'OldSolution`.

Another alternative is to create a new solution called `NewSolution` from scratch and add all the references and dependencies of `OldSolution` manually. In a language like C# where the order of the files does not matter this would be relatively easy. But in F# besides copying the files you have to reorder them appropriately. The whole process becomes quite time consuming.

I wonder if Visual Studio 2017 has a way to make a copy of `OldSolution` with all names of folders, etc. renamed to `NewSolution`.

Comment: With "Items" you mean projects? Those can't be renamed automatically; the only real way is to rename the folders and then edit the .sln and .fsproj files manually.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev - I did a text search within the root folder and found out that besides the .sln and .fsproj files the AssemblyInfo.fs file also contains the string `OldSolution`. The same is true also of a bunch of files in the OldSolution\bin\Debug, OldSolution\bin\Release, OldSolution\obj\Debug, OldSolution\obj\Release folders. Do I have to edit all these files too?

Comment: @Soldalma `bin` and `obj` can be safely deleted. They will be regenerated on next build. I‘d also switch to the new project format which relies more on conventions and thus needs no explicit strings (except namespaces in code files). Simply copy-renaming a solution (keeping projects the same) then boils down to copying the folder and renaming the `.sln` file.

Comment: @CaringDev - Thanks. How do I switch to the new project format?

Comment: @Soldalma Unfortunately AFAIK there’s no easy way to migrate. Either create a new project or edit the old towards becoming a new one. As a template create a new netstandard / core project and switch to the desired target framework (VS templates only create the new format for netcore / standard). For simply renaming the _solution_ old format is OK. Renaming _projects_ is easier with the new format though.

Comment: @CaringDev - Where can I get info on the new vs old project formats?

Comment: @Soldalma I don't have a preferred source, https://www.google.com/search?q=project+format+new+old+visual+studio should get you a long way though. For me the first hit is a nice description of how to migrate.